# Postgresql query exception will drop connection to database

Tags: java, database, networking, jdbc, timeout

So, I got this problem. I'm using JDBC, and every time if query get SQL exception and I/O error, the connection to pgsql database will be dropped automatically.

As a result, I have to check if the connection is open before every query, and if it's not open, I'll open it again.

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Also I know even I give perfect connection parameters, the connection could randomly drop.

Anyone knows how to set connection parameter to auto-check connections and reopen it in case connections down?

Currently I'm not using connection pooling.

Following is my code to set connection properties:

```
Properties pgsqlInfo = new Properties();
pgsqlInfo.setProperty("user", userName);
pgsqlInfo.setProperty("password", password);
pgsqlInfo.setProperty("ssl", "true");
pgsqlInfo.setProperty("loginTimeout", "0");
pgsqlInfo.setProperty("tcpKeepAlive", "true");
pgsqlInfo.setProperty("socketTimeout", "0");

con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url + "/" + dbName, pgsqlInfo);
```

Comment: I found this resource which may help you solve your problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pgsql.interfaces.jdbc/TC-pt0zmGrg

Comment: @ThomasLangston ths link is about connections timing out, regardless of query exceptions

Comment: please provide the code and exception

Comment: I/O error doesn't seem to be a SQL problem. It looks such as connection timeout or something so on. Also probably SQLException can be the final expcetion with its IO error as a reason. Please provide more information about it: how you create the connection, the code you run (statement/prepared statement/callable statement), full stack trace, probably the postgresql.conf too

Comment: You guys are right, I think this may be caused by timeout. I showed my settings above. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you connecting via a NAT router to a remote server? If so, you need to be doing some kind of keep-alive or the TCP connection tracking tables will expire the connection.